imagettftext does not work while imagestring works fine
I have an issue with my PHP code.
I want to add text to an image.
When using imagestring(), the image displays fine with the text on top, but it's written very very small.
And it's impossible to increase the size with imagestring().
I saw that it's rather recommended to use imagettftext(), but when I use this function, the image doesn't display.
I get no errors, it just displays the alt tag text.
I've tried dozens and dozens of different function calls but none have worked.
Here's my code:
$idQuiz = $_GET['qz'];
$user = UtilisateursManager::getList(null, ['idUtilisateur'=>$_SESSION['utilisateur']->getIdUtilisateur()])[0];
$name = $user->getPrenomUtilisateur().' '.$user->getNomUtilisateur();

$font = './FONTS/RedditMono-Black.ttf';
$fontSize = 50;
$img = "./IMG/certificatRealisation.jpg";
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($img);
$color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 0, 0);
// imagestring($image, 5, 600, 700, $name, $color);
imagettftext($image, 52, 0, 500, 600, $color, $font, $name);

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($image);
imagedestroy($image);


"the image doesn't display" - if your PHP script output any error messages, that will of course invalidate the image data - and the browser can only display the "broken image" placeholder. Go check what response the request actually got, using the network panel of your browser dev tools.
